# Не могу запустить OpenGL приложение на Linux

Tags: java, linux

Я пытаюсь запустить свой приложение (в разрешении 800x600)(написана на Java с помощью библиотеки LWJGL) и получаю ошибку:

```
X Error of failed request:  RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RenderFreePicture)
Picture id in failed request: 0x3400065
Serial number of failed request:  3074
Current serial number in output stream:  3100
```

Как исправить это и из за чего данная ошибка может возникать?

P.S.
Видео карта: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphic Controller
ОС: Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: не про вашу ошибку? http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2014/08/java-8-swing-related-jvm-crash-on-linux.html